# Facebook Pixel ReferenceError: Set is not defined (<IE11)

Tags: javascript, facebook-pixel

We're trying to implement Facebook Pixel on a website and it's working in all browsers except in Internet Explorer 11 or below. The exact error what we're getting is: Facebook Pixel Error: ReferenceError: Set is not defined.

We were not able to find any info whatsoever with regards to this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen this too. I don't think IE11 and below support Set as its a relatively new ES6 feature but I'm unsure as why Pixel code is trying to use it in these environments.

Possibly related, are you loading Facebook Pixel via GTM?

```
 function p() {
            var s = []
              , t = b.querySelectorAll('[itemscope]')
              , u = new Set();
            for (var v = t.length - 1; v >= 0; v--) {
                var w = t[v]
                  , x = w.querySelectorAll('[itemprop]')
                  , y = w.getAttribute('itemtype');
```

---

Update:
After reporting this bug to Facebook it has now been resolved.

---

This should now be resolved. Thanks for flagging this, and thanks for your patience while we addressed the issue. Please ensure you are not caching an older version of the file.

Thanks,

Ram

Comment: Yes in fact I was loading the Pixel through GTM, although when we changed it to directly loading the pixel, it made no effect.

Comment: We filled a bug report on facebook platform. This could be a long process... Thanks for trying the direct approach (and saving me an experiment) I had pondered the possibility that they were serving ES6 based on some hacky detection possibly compromised via GTM loading, but it seems not the case. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/305206443266436/

Comment: From Facebook team: Thank you for the additional context.

We have managed to reproduce this issue and it appears to be a valid bug. We are assigning this to the appropriate team.

Ram